# S3 bucket Failover

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53, cname

I have two S3 buckets **my-east-bucket** and **my-west-bucket**. All my applications send their logs to my-east-bucket by default. I want to develop a mechanism which automatically **redirects my file copy request to my-west-bucket when my-east-bucket is unreachable**. Is there a way I can use another layer (CNAME or similar) which first checks if east bucket is reachable and if not redirect my request to west bucket? **I do not want to change my copy command/code.**

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your copy command/code? This is important because it will impact how you can reference the buckets. For example, if you are using `aws s3 cp`, then you need to refer to a specific bucket. However, if you are referring to a URL, then Route 53 could resolve the URL based upon a health check. Also, if you want this feature, why would you be unwilling to change your code?

Comment: Why would a bucket be unreachable?  S3 is a highly-available service.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot : It's unreachable right now in east-1 region! also see this where netfilx and pintrest went down as a result https://www.cloudave.com/20726/how-to-synch-s3-buckets-in-aws-and-design-for-failover/  here's a good post about S3 replication https://www.cloudendure.com/blog/aws-s3-replication-6-things-know/

Comment: @SSED you got me!  Some of my services were affected as well.  I am familiar with S3 replication, as well as my own solution which uses S3 event notifications to replicate objects to a bucket in GCS in near real time.  None of that would be fully relevant to the question at hand, since it's about *write* access failover.  My question, here, was actually intended to probe OP's understanding of the likelihood of such an issue -- which, in spite of today's events, is still low.  Also, the "I don't want to change my code" premise of the question seems somewhat unreasonable.